# Dynamically Building Linq to Entities Lambda Expression with Concatenated Properties

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities

I recently ran into the requirement to implement server side filtering for a Kendo UI grid control. Since the comparison operator(s) in the linq to entities lambda expressions wouldn't be known at compile time, it was necessary to build the expressions dynamically. I've never had the need to do this before, but I did enough digging to figure out how to build simple lambda expressions from expression trees. As an example, I build the expression for a simple filter such as `people.Where(person => person.LastName == "Doe")` as follows:

```
ParameterExpression filterParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");
MemberExpression left = Expression.Property(filterParam, "LastName");
ConstantExpression right = Expression.Constant("Doe", typeof(string));
BinaryExpression predicate = Expression.Equal(left, right);
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>(predicate, filterParam);

IQueryable<Person> filtered = people.Where(lambda);
```

Ok, so on to the question. I encountered the need to do something similar to above except filtering by full name instead of just last name. I don't have a field in my database for full name--just separate first and last name fields, so I can't reference a single property for this. I need to concatenate the two properties in the expression so that the resulting lambda would look like:

```
people.Where(person => (person.firstName + person.LastName) == "JohnDoe")
```

I haven't been able to find an example showing how to dynamically build a lambda like that from expression trees. I'm assuming it must be possible--it doesn't seem like that crazy of a scenario, does it?

Edit: I'd also be interested in knowing how to do:

```
people.Where(person => (person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName) == "John Doe")
```

Edit2: The solution to this one is a pretty simple change from king king's answer:

```
ParameterExpression filterParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "person");
MemberExpression first = Expression.Property(filterParam, "FirstName");
MemberExpression last = Expression.Property(filterParam, "LastName");
Type strType = typeof(string);

MethodCallExpression concat = Expression.Call(typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new [] { strType, strType, strType }),
    first, Expression.Constant(" ", strType), last);

ConstantExpression right = Expression.Constant("John Doe", strType);
BinaryExpression predicate = Expression.Equals(concat, right);
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(predicate, filterParam);

IQueryable<Person> filtered = people.Where(lambda);
```

Comment: A great way to figure out how to build a given expression is to use LinqPad (free). Just create the expression as a variable and dump it (Expression<Func<Person, bool>> e = p => ...; p.Dump()

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a `MethodCallExpression` to use the `string.Concat` method:

```
var firstName = Expression.Property(filterParam, "FirstName");
var lastName = Expression.Property(filterParam, "LastName");
var concat = Expression.Call(typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new [] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }),
                             firstName, lastName);
BinaryExpression predicate = Expression.Equal(concat, right);
//....
```

Comment: Very nice, works like a charm with one slight modification. I get a `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException` using the overload of GetMethod you have there. Changing it to `GetMethod("Concat", new [] { typeof(string), typeof(string) })` fixes that.  Could you edit your answer to use an overload that includes the parameter type array, so I can accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make this easier and reusable, I do define extra properties on the Entity model by using [PropertyTranslator](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Linq.PropertyTranslator/) in combination with [QueryInterceptor](http://www.nuget.org/packages/QueryInterceptor/).

With this code you can define the FullName property on the Entity model like this:

```
public class Person
{
    private static readonly CompiledExpressionMap<Employee, string> FullNameExpr =
        DefaultTranslationOf<Employee>.Property(e => e.FullName).Is(e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName);

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FullNameExpr.Evaluate(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And just use this Fullname property in a query like:

```
IQueryable<Person> filtered = people
    .InterceptWith(new PropertyVisitor()).AsQueryable()
    .Where(p => p.FullName == "John Doe");
```

I'm not sure if you can implement this in your design, but if possible investigate this option.

You can check the example project [here](http://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx/).